# Ignore componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps warning messages

Tags: react-native

These annoying messages appear all the time even I don't use these functions in my code. The problem is that some of my dependencies use them. They block the screen of the simulator and the debugger. I have to close them all the time and these messages are not relevant for my development. How can I ignore them?

[image: Message in debugger]

[image: Message in iPhone simulator]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To ignore specific YellowBox messages:

```
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';

class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
      'Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated',
      'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated',
    ]);

  }
...
```

UPDATE: As @Auticcat points out, this only applies to the simulator.

Comment: Note that this will hide them from the screen on the emulator/device. They will still be visible in the console debugger

Comment: @Auticcat that's right! Any idea of how to ignore them also on the debugger? Thanks

Comment: I just learned to live with it. In some cases i changed the node_modules myself but it never found a way to fully get rid of em from the console. You can hide all warnings in console using the button that says "default levels" but i would not suggest using it