# How to fix Reactive Native warnings about componentWillMount and componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I do not found those in my application code. I am using Reactive native and expo for a super simple app (hello world level).

These show up in my console and take up a lot of space

```
bundle.js:40674 Warning: componentWillMount has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See ... for details.

* Move code with side effects to componentDidMount, and set initial state in the constructor.
* Rename componentWillMount to UNSAFE_componentWillMount to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: ScrollView
...

bundle.js:40674 Warning: componentWillReceiveProps has been renamed, and is not recommended for use. See ... for details.

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate.
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps. ...
* Rename componentWillReceiveProps to UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps to suppress this warning in non-strict mode. In React 17.x, only the UNSAFE_ name will work. To rename all deprecated lifecycles to their new names, you can run `npx react-codemod rename-unsafe-lifecycles` in your project source folder.

Please update the following components: TouchableOpacity
```

Given I can't find them, is there a way to fix them?  I don't want to just ignore them or cover them up because that may lead to future issues being even harder to find.

Comment: i had to remove urls because SO was being grumpy about them (shortenings) and I don't have time or desire to fix them just because of that.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57427069/ignore-componentwillmount-and-componentwillreceiveprops-warning-messages did not address

Answer (score 0):

They are most likely packages in your `node_modules` folder.  You can check for updates to the packages, or use [`patch-package`](https://github.com/ds300/patch-package) to add the `_UNSAFE` flag to suppress the warnings.